# Neo4j - how to import csv having special characters

Tags: neo4j, cypher, csv-import

I am trying to import csv file which has some special characters like `' , " , \` when I am running this query -

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "http://192.168.11.121/movie-reco-db/movie_node.csv" as row
CREATE (:Movie_new {movieId: row.movie_id, title: row.title, runtime: row.runtime, metaScore: row.meta_score, imdbRating: row.IMDB_rating, imdbVotes: row.IMDB_votes , released: row.released , description: row.description , watchCount: row.watch_count , country: row.country ,
category: row.category , award: row.award , plot: row.plot , timestamp: row.timestamp})
```

It throws an error -

```
At http://192.168.11.121/movie-reco-db/movie_node.csv:35 -  there's a field starting with a quote and whereas it ends that quote there seems to be characters in that field after that ending quote. That isn't supported. This is what I read: ' Awesome skills performed by skillful players! Football Circus! If you like my work, become a fan on facebook",0,USA,Football,N/A,N/A,1466776986
260,T.J. Miller: No Real Reason,0,0,7.4,70,2011-11-15," '
```

I debug the file and remove `\` from the line causing problem , then re-run the above query , it worked well. Is there any better way to do it by query or I have to find and remove such kind of characters each time ?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear that the quote character is configurable for LOAD CSV (like the FIELDTERMINATOR is):

- http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#csv-file-format

If you're creating a new Database, you could look into using the neo4j-import tool which does appear to have the option to configure the quote character (and then just set it to a character you know won't be in your csv files (say for example a pipe symbol |):

- http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/deployment/#import-tool

Otherwise, yes, you're going to need to run a cleansing process on your input files prior to loading.

Comment: Is there any other feasible way to do this ? removing it directly from file could be cumbersome.